# Having trouble in python sending cookies using request to scrape

Tags: python, cookies, beautifulsoup, python-requests

A while back I wrote a program in Java to scrape my university's course catalog. I decided to switch over to python since I needed something more lightweight for my purposes.

For my java scraper I used jSoup. For my python project I am using the BeautifulSoup and requests libraries.

The url that I'm trying to access: https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?s=MAT&n=243&t=2157&e=open&hon=F

The issue is that without the correct cookies the link will redirect asking you if you are looking for on campus courses or online courses. Once you chose on-campus the link will then work. I did some research and found that the request was cookie dependent. In java the code works fine and looks like this:

```
Document doc = null;
    String url = "https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?s=MAT&n=243&t=2157&e=open&hon=F";

    try {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .cookie("onlineCampusSelection", "C");
        connection.timeout(0);
        doc = connection.get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I am trying to recreate this in python and this is what I have so far.

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?s=MAT&n=243&t=2157&e=open&hon=F'
cookies = dict(onlineCampusSelection = 'C')

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
print r.text
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

I've read the documentation for requests and haven't found my solution. When I run the code this is the error that I'm receiving.
[Connection Forcibly Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ycjb.png)

Comment: I haven't dug down much but did get "Max retries exceeded with url" when testing your code. Are you sure the java is still working.. you may have angered the server.

Comment: Yes, I am positive the Java is still working. I changed the url to reflect a different search on the course catalog and fed it to my java program (and it ran) and I fed it to my python program (and it crashed).